# How to create a many-to-many with ASPNet EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to create a contact list in my application. I therefore created a mapping table between ApplicationUsers:

```
public class UserContacts
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Contact { get; set; }
}
```

And then registered the relations between my ApplicationUser and this table:

```
builder.Entity<UserContacts>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Contact)
            .WithMany(p => p.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContactId);

builder.Entity<UserContacts>()
            .HasOne(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
```

And added a property in my ApplicationUser class:

```
public virtual ICollection<UserContacts> Contacts { get; set; }
```

But whenever I try to update the database I get the following error:

Cannot create a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.Contacts' and 'UserContacts.User', because there already is a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.Contacts' and 'UserContacts.Contact'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

Can you please explain to me what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another collection to ApplicationUser:

```
public virtual ICollection<UserContacts> **Users** { get; set; }
```

Then change the fluent code to point there (they can't point to same collection):

```
builder.Entity<UserContacts>()
            .HasOne(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(p => **p.Users**)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
```